# How do I create a list of classes which always have a predefined value set in AutoFixture?

Tags: c#, autofixture

how do I create a collection of classes which always have a certain predefined value set in AutoFixture?

```
Fixture.Register<IList<Child>>(() => Fixture.CreateMany<Child>().ToList());
```

Say the child class has the following:

```
public class Child
{
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public int ChildId { get; set; }

    public string ChildName { get; set; }
    public int ChildValue { get; set; }
}
```

How do I ensure the anonymous classes always have the same parent Id whilst all other properties can be random?  I guess it would also be advisable to set ChildId to 0 too as these will be pushed into a database in a repository data test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
fixture.Customize<Child>(c => c.With(x => x.ParentId, 42).With(x => x.ChildId, 0));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that.  I actually just decided on chaining up 2 .Without() as the EF code-first model I'm using has both the Child PK and Parent FK defined inside the Child class. I just set both to 0 in the 2 Without() statements and let EF fill them in after they are inserted.