# Is it possible to generate C# Dictionary with autofixture and injection

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dictionary, fixtures, autofixture

Is it possible to implement something like this with autofixture injection?

```
        // Fixture setup
        var fields = _fixture.CreateMany<CsvDbUpdateFieldModel>(1).ToList();
        _fixture.Inject(fields);

        var kvp = _fixture.CreateMany<KeyValuePair<int, IList<CsvDbUpdateFieldModel>>>(1);
        _fixture.Inject(kvp);

        var dictionary = _fixture.Create<IDictionary<int, IList<CsvDbUpdateFieldModel>>>();
        _fixture.Inject(dictionary);

        ...
```

What I want is to get a Dictionary with one kvp, with `IList<CsvDbUpdateFieldModel>` containing 1 element, which declared before. But now AutoFixture create `IList<CsvDbUpdateFieldModel>` with 3 randomly generated items, which probably not that I want. May be some details of AutoFixture Dictionary creation should help me..

I know how to create only one, and how to build dictionary from scratch. I ask how to force AutoFixture to use injected before kvp to automatically build dictionary, using injection mechanism

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/37511519/126014

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/19286476/126014

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/5555054/126014

Comment: all of this is not that I ask, @MarkSeemann is there anyway to force autofixture use before injected list of kvp to automatically create dictionary, without zipping, merging or manually constructing the dictionary?

Comment: As far as I know is `Inject` used for Mocks (AutoMoq). You should try `Freeze()` instead.You know that MarkSeemann is the author of Autofixture

Comment: @Jehof you also can use it like in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29270580/createmany-where-only-1-element-contains-certain-value/39973891#39973891, I just trying to figure how it all works, and I think it's something dictionary specific and how autofixture create it internally, because in simple cases everythink works